# Size of array of vectors of different sizes cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have a function which accepts  array of vectors of different sizes I want to know how many vectors are present in array

```
int dfs(vector<int> g[])
{
   int n=?;//(no. of vector in array)
}
```

Comment: You cannot, pass in the size separately or use a top level `vector<T>`.

Comment: I am solving a functional problem and this is what i am getting as parameter which cannot be changed

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ does not work this way. This cannot be done in C++.

Comment: Oh Okay.Thanks !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this in C++: an array type in a function parameter decays to a pointer, which has no size information.

The best option is to take the parameter as a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, but you mention in a comment that that is not possible.

One other option, if you are sure you will be passed an array (in comparison to a pointer to an array) is to change the definition to something like this:

```cpp
template <std::size_t n>
int dfs(std::vector<int>(&g)[n]) {
  // n is the number of elements in the array
}
```